# jQuery Validation engine, past and future date validation by dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: jquery, validation, date, jquery-validation-engine

I am new in jQuery. I am using jQuery version 1.8.3. In my ASP.NET Web application, I am using jQuery Validation engine to validate date. I am dynamically creating HTML text input which allows user to enter date only in dd/mm/yyyy format and here I am assigning both past and future validators to texbox. I want to validate date in dd/mm/yyyy format by using past and future validators in such way that user should allow enter only the date between the value given to past and future. And If user enter date beyond given restriction it should show date in message in dd/mm/yyyy format too.

But what happening is; past and future date validators validating only when I pass date in yyyy-mm-dd format and I have to enter date in textbox in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Everyone opinions are welcome

What I tried till now is as follows:

```
HtmlGenericControl l_oHGC = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divCustomFields.Controls.Add(l_oHGC);
TextBox l_oTXT = new TextBox();
l_oHGC.Controls.Add(l_oTXT);
l_oTXT.Text = Convert.ToDateTime("Apr 16 2014 12:00AM").ToString(gc.APP_DATEFORMAT_DD_MM_YYYY);
l_oTXT.MaxLength = 10;
l_oTXT.CssClass = "calender validate[custom[date],past[" + Convert.ToDateTime("Dec 31 2050 12:00AM").ToString(gc.APP_DATEFORMAT_DD_MM_YYYY) + "],future[" + Convert.ToDateTime("Apr 26 2014 12:00AM").ToString(gc.APP_DATEFORMAT_DD_MM_YYYY) + "]]";
```

**In jquery.validationEngine-en.js I did following changes**

```
 "past": {
    "regex": /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/,
                "alertText": "* Date prior to "
        },
  "future": {
     "regex": /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/,
                "alertText": "* Date past "
        },  
    "date": {
       "regex": /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/,
                "alertText": "* Invalid date, must be in DD/MM/YYYY format"
       },
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: **you can't do `past` and `future` validations when date is specified in a custom format.** Out-of-the-box, it supports only dates in ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY/MM/DD).

The bad news is that changes in the language file (`jquery.validationEngine-en.js`) will not affect parsing dates for these validations.

The reason is that the ISO formats is hardcoded in the following method of the `jquery.validationEngine.js`:

```
/**
* Parses an ISO date
* @param {String} d
*/
_parseDate: function(d) {

    var dateParts = d.split("-");
    if(dateParts==d)
        dateParts = d.split("/");
    if(dateParts==d) {
        dateParts = d.split(".");
        return new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);
    }
    return new Date(dateParts[0], (dateParts[1] - 1) ,dateParts[2]);
},
```

Hence, you have to either use the `YYYY/MM/DD` format instead of the desired `dd/mm/yyyy` or write your own parsing method instead of `_parseDate`to suit your needs.

If you'd prefer the second way, here is the bad news number 2: **there is no extension point which could be used to override this behavior via your own JS**. So you need to edit `jquery.validationEngine.js` directly and make sure that you will not overwrite your changes when you will be updating the `jQuery.validationEngine` plugin in the future.

Comment: @Rahul: Was my answer helpful? If so feel free to accept/upvote it or provide some feedback. Otherwise, this thread looks abandoned and useless for other readers. Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you do this with [`funcCall`](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#funccallmethodname) instead of [`custom`](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#customregex_name)?